# What happens if the first `FIN` packet lost in TCP connections?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have an agent, say `A`, running and sending information to my server, say `S`. `A`'s socket is configured as `keepalive`, and when the network between `A` and `S` is poor, `A` would detect the connection error and try to reconnect to `S`. I can observe sometimes the TCP connection status on `A` is `FIN_WAIT1`, meaning `A` sends a `FIN` packet and waits. But this `FIN` packet seems lost because on `S` I can see many `ESTABLISHED` connections between `A` and `S`, where normally there should be only one.

Does TCP fail in this situation, or what do I miss?

Comment: If all packets are lost, the socket will eventually time out, close and be removed. The timeouts can however take a lot of time, if they are adjusted so

Answer (score 0):

It is retransmitted in the absence of an ACK, like any other TCP segment.

Comment: So I suppose the retransmitted `FIN`s are also lost?

Comment: yip there are no retrans FINs either the frames stop